# How to stop clearing between command buffers?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm trying to get ImGui working in my engine but having some trouble "overlaying" it over my cube mesh. I split the two in seperate command buffers like

```
std::array<VkCommandBuffer, 2> cmdbuffers = { commandBuffers[imageIndex], imguicmdbuffers[imageIndex] };
```

And then in my queue submit info I put the command buffer count to 2 and pass it the data like so

```
submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 2;
submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = cmdbuffers.data();
```

But what happens now is that it only renders imgui, or if I switch the order in the array it only renders the cube, never both. Is it because they share the same render pass? I changed the `VkRenderPassBeginInfo` clear color to double check and indeed it either clears yellow and draws imgui or clears red and draws the cube. I've tried setting the clear alpha to 0 but that doesn't work and seems like a hack anyway. I feel like I lack understanding of how it submits and executes the command buffers and how it's tied to render passes/framebuffers, so whats up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following statements (that is, assuming they are accurate):

- > they share the same render pass
- > in my queue submit info I put the command buffer count to 2
- > VkRenderPassBeginInfo clear color

Certain things about the nature of your rendering become apparent (things you didn't directly state or provide code for). First, you are submitting two separate command buffers directly to the queue. Only primary command buffers can be submitted to the queue.

Second, by the nature of render passes, a render pass instance cannot span primary command buffers. So you must have two render pass instances.

Third, you specify that you can change the clear color of the image when you begin the render pass instance. Ergo, the render pass must specify that the image gets cleared as its load-op.

From all of this, I conclude that you are beginning the same `VkRenderPass` twice. A render pass that, as previously deduced, is set to *clear the image* at the beginning of the render pass instance. Which will dutifully happen both times, the second of which will wipe out everything that was rendered to that image beforehand.

Basically, you have two rendering operations, using a render pass that's set to destroy the data created by any previous rendering operation to the images it uses. That's not going to work.

You have a few ways of resolving this.

My preferred way would be to start employing secondary command buffers. I don't know if ImGui can be given a CB to record its data into. But if it can, I would suggest making it record its data into a secondary CB. You can then execute that secondary CB into the appropriate subpass of your renderpass. And thus, you don't submit two primary CBs; you only submit one.

Alternatively, you can make a new `VkRenderPass` which doesn't clear the previous image; it should load the image data instead. Your second rendering operation would use that render pass, while your initial one would retain the clear load-op.

Worst-case scenario, you can have the second operation render to an entirely different image, and then merge it with the primary image in a third rendering operation.

Comment: Thank you!, I did not know about secondary command buffers. I was able to record ImGui into one and tie it to the render pass using command buffer inheritance info.